# Spring Session – Support for other Backend Implementations other then Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-session

I would like to use "Spring Session" in my current project, but it seems that currently only Redis is a supported backend database. The official documentation is not talking about any other support yet.

Are there alternative implementations for other databases? For example, what about Memcached or Couchbase Support, which are fast Key-/Value Stores as well?

Comment: Couchbase is far superior to Memcached. Its has memcached compatible protocol...but its a noSQL DB (persistent cache) but Memcached it just distributed memory based cache.
I used Couchbase as a distributed cache solution (key/value) and also as a noSQL DB to store business data in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK only redis and hazelcast is supported but maybe you can find some 3rd party. Or you might want to implement it by yourself (and make it open source). It does not seems to be that complicated - see

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.0.1.RELEASE/samples/hazelcast/src/main/java/sample/Initializer.java

It looks like you just need to implement your [SessionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/SessionRepository.html) and use proper HTTP filter.